# Importing 'render' from @testing-library/react in a jsx file is erroring out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

a little stuck on this one. I'm introducing react unit testing into my teams node/react project. We've had jest unit tests for our backend and utils in FE for a long time but no react testing.

I'm following the testing guide via https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests

My issue is that, I've created the test file the exact same way all our other unit tests are created and running properly. I've put a fake test case in the file:

```
import React from 'react';
//import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('test', () => {
  it('tests', () => {
    expect(true).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

And this test case executes as expected. However, as soon as I uncomment the `import { render }` line, it's breaking on the following error:

```
 FAIL  */__tests__/client/views/components/componentToTest.test.jsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    */node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/helpers.js:44
        } catch {// not using Jest's modern fake timers
                ^
    
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
      
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:316:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/pretty-dom.js:13:16)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/config.js:11:18)
```

At a total loss for what's going on here, can't find anyone w/ a similar issue. My IDE even correctly shows me what the render method looks like, so I know its importing properly.

I've installed all of the packages suggested in the guide, and obviously have jest config'd to run jsx files (since the test works, but just breaks on the import)

An answer would be great, but really would love to just be pointed in the right direction of how to resolve this as well.

Thanks!

Also worth noting, I have `babel-jest` and `jest-dom` setup, as I know thats the answer to a lot of similar issues.

Comment: I have the same issue when tests were running on node v8.17.0. On Node v10 and v13 all work.

Comment: Oh you're actually 100% right. Yesterday, I was ripping my hair out on this one all day. Finally, my machine ended up crashing, and when I loaded it back up again it was working. I was super confused, but just realized now thanks to your comment that yesterday I was running v8.7.0 as I had to deploy a service that uses that version earlier, and never switched back to v10. When my computer crashed, it reset my version back to v10, which is why its running properly. Good call here, thank you. How did you figure out it was a versioning issue w/ node itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that optional catch bindings in JavaScript (when you declare a catch block without binding an error: `try {} catch {}` instead of `try {} catch(error) {}`) only works on Node V10+.

Additionally, testing library supports Node V10+.

To get around it, you need to run the tests on Node V10+ and make sure to setup babel to use the current node version in your system, with the proper transforms.

Check out the [Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel) for more information.

P.S.: you can find more info about this issue [here](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/660).

Comment: Sincerest apologies for the lag on accepting this answer. This was it, thanks for the answer and additional context.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like Babel needs to transform the js files in `/node_modules/@testing-library` and in your case its not doing that. I suspect that your your jest config (either defined in `package.json` or in `jest.config.js`) needs to be fixed so that babel does indeed transform those files.

A quick fix would be to set `transformIgnorePatterns` as an empty array. By default `transformIgnorePatterns` is set to `"/node_modules/"` and setting it to an empty array would stop the node_module files from being ignored So it could be something like this.

```js
...
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
  "^.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-css-modules-transform"
},
"transformIgnorePatterns": [],
....
```

The problem with this solution is that all the files in node_modules will be transformed and this could make the test run slow. A better solution would be to set transformIgnorePatterns to a regex pattern that includes all node_modules files EXCEPT @testing-library. I'm not an expert on regex so I'll leave you to figure that out.

Comment: So it looks like this regex pattern for `"transformIgnorePatterns"` worked `"[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\][^@testing-library/].+\\.(js|jsx)$",`